# How can i fetch Arraylist data and save into String in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want load data from server into array. **My json is :** 
I want load data from server into array. **My json is :**

```
{
    "mapmarkers": {
        "markers":[{
            "lat": 35.651005,
            "long": 51.325113,
            "title": "Ł…Ł†Ų·Ł‚Ł‡ 1",
            "snippet": "ŲŖŁŲ¶ŪŲ­Ų§ŲŖ Ł…Ų±ŲØŁŲ· ŲØŁ‡ Ł…Ł†Ų·Ł‚Ł‡ 1"
        },{
            "lat": 35.651964,
            "long": 51.324984,
            "title": "Ł…Ł†Ų·Ł‚Ł‡ 2",
            "snippet": "ŲŖŁŲ¶ŪŲ­Ų§ŲŖ 2"
        },{
            "lat": 35.649521,
            "long": 51.327027,
            "title": "Ł…Ł†Ų·Ł‚Ł‡ 3",
            "snippet": "ŲŖŁŲ¶ŪŲ­Ų§ŲŖ 3"
        },{
            "lat": 35.649799,
            "long": 51.325620,
            "title": "Ł…Ł†Ų·Ł‚Ł‡ 4",
            "snippet": "ŲŖŁŲ¶ŪŲ­Ų§ŲŖ 4"
        },{
            "lat": 35.650235,
            "long": 51.324697,
            "title": "Ł…Ł†Ų·Ł‚Ł‡ 5",
            "snippet": "ŲŖŁŲ¶ŪŲ­Ų§ŲŖ 5"
        }
}
```

With this code, I get data from server and set into arrayList :

```
private ArrayList<Markerinfo> model = new ArrayList<Markerinfo>();

public void initRequest() {
    APIinterface api = APIrequest.getCient().create(APIinterface.class);
    Call<Mapmarkers> call = api.getMarkerResponse();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Mapmarkers>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Mapmarkers> call, Response<Mapmarkers> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                model.addAll(response.body().getMarkers());
                for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
                    createMarker(model.get(i).getLat(), model.get(i).getLong(), model.get(i).getTitle(), model.get(i).getSnippet());
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(model.get(i).getLat(), model.get(i).getLong());
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Mapmarkers> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

For example, I want save just below lat and lang into **String address3;**

```
"lat": 35.649521,
        "long": 51.327027,
```

how can it?

Comment: there are array of lat, long... how do you want to save using a single `address3`..?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, I can save and show all of list and it's ok. but I want save single address in String. can you help me?

Comment: you can concat the lat and long string to your address variable...also you can use a LatLng object to store the value as latitude and longitude

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, can you send me code? I am amateur. please

Comment: okay ...i will write an answer..

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, thanks, I will waite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String `ArrayList` to store all `addresses` for all `Markerinfo`.

**Try this:**

```
private ArrayList<Markerinfo> model = new ArrayList<Markerinfo>();
private ArrayList<String> addressList= new ArrayList<String>();

public void initRequest() {
    APIinterface api = APIrequest.getCient().create(APIinterface.class);
    Call<Mapmarkers> call = api.getMarkerResponse();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Mapmarkers>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Mapmarkers> call, Response<Mapmarkers> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                model.addAll(response.body().getMarkers());
                for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {

                    // Add address to list
                    addressList.add(String.valueOf(model.get(i).getLat()) + ", " + String.valueOf( model.get(i).getLong()));

                    createMarker(model.get(i).getLat(), model.get(i).getLong(), model.get(i).getTitle(), model.get(i).getSnippet());
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(model.get(i).getLat(), model.get(i).getLong());
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Mapmarkers> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

Use `addressList` values later as per your needs.

```
String address = addressList.get(0);  // For example 1st address <"lat": 35.651005, "long": 51.325113>
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

try this : convert the Double value to string and add them..

```
  String address = String.valueOf(model.get(i).getLat()) + String.valueOf( model.get(i).getLong());
```

**EDIT**

For specific item position use:

```
 String address; //declare outside

for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
                if(i == 2) { //third item
                    address = String.valueOf(model.get(i).getLat()) + String.valueOf( model.get(i).getLong());
                    }
                    createMarker(model.get(i).getLat(), model.get(i).getLong(), model.get(i).getTitle(), model.get(i).getSnippet());
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(model.get(i).getLat(), model.get(i).getLong());
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
                }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I wrote this code in my above codes : `LatLng latLng = new LatLng(model.get(i).getLat(), model.get(i).getLong());`  but this code just fetch lastet of items in list! but I want get my custom item, for example item 3